# Issue with program executed by crontab

Tags: c, linux, memory, arm, embedded-linux

I've coded a program in c for an embedded system (Devkit8000, which is a clone of the well known BeagleBoard) running Angstrom Linux.

The program creates a couple of threads, on of them is responsible of taking pictures with a camera connected to the board, and right now the second thread only moves that images to another path. The program should be running during the whole day, and the only way to stop it is sending a signal.

I edited the crontab to launch the program in a specific hour and to send a signal when it has to stop, the issue is that launching the program in this way cause the process to be killed after some time running, but, if i launch the program manually (through the command line), it works perfectly and dont get stopped.

I have no idea about the reason of this different behaviour between crontab and command line. I've checked the system logs but didnt find anything useful. I've also been reading a little and find that the OS can kill a process if it is using so much resources, but doesnt make sense that this happens in only 1 scenario (crontab vs manually)...

Any clue about what is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The environment variables are, typically, not the same when running something from crontab, compared to command line. Make sure that all relevant `PATH` variables are set before you start your application. Also make sure that any environment variables that might be used by libraries in your application has the expected value.

Comment: As i said to cdarke, i'll take a look in my code to check if its using any $ENV variable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that running a job through cron invokes a non-interactive non-login shell.  The effect of that depends on the default shell for your user.  For example, if you are using Korn shell or Bash then your .profile will not be executed, as it would on an interactive login shell.  Korn shell 88 will execute .kshrc (the $ENV file) but ksh93 will not.
So, a good start might be to call your program from a script, after first "sourcing" your .profile file:

```
. $HOME/.profile
```

Failing that... When you say that the process is "killed", do you get such a message?  If so, then that sounds like someone sending SIGKILL, i.e. `kill -9`.  If not, then maybe you could run strace or ltrace to find out at what point it dies.

Comment: As far as i know, the program dont use any $ENV variable, thats the reason of why this is a really weird behaviour. Anyway, i'll check the code again to be sure.

About the "killing" problem... I dont get that message anywhere (not even in the system logs), and i dont think other user are sending SIGKILL because no one else have access to this board. I only have the feeling that beacause of the memory usage, the OS is the one killing my process, so i'll try to check again with the strace and ltrace as u suggested.

Comment: ENV is used by the shell, not by the program.  It give the name of the (usually) .kshrc file.